# PayU thank you page's redirect button

Tags: javascript, php, payu

Can anyone tell me how give link to the button on the thank you page after customer succesfuly payed on PayU?
The link is something like this:
https://secure.payu.com/pay/?orderId=1234567890&token=long1234567890#/status

After payment I need to redirect the user back to a certain page. We are using Js and PHP.

Comment: [Their APIs](https://www.google.com/search?q=payu+api) do not help?

Comment: Yeah, it seems the continueUrl what I need here: https://developers.payu.com/en/restapi.html#references_api_parameters